# JasperReports: Passing in a list of lists as a datasource

Tags: list, jasper-reports

I need to populate a few subreports with lists of different objects. Basically lets say i have the following:
Subreport on used Vehicles
Subreport on new Vehicles

I create a vehicle bean class with variables as strings and create getter and setter methods for the same. Then in my datasource I pass in a `List<List<String>>` as detailRows. detailRows contains a list for new vehicles and a list for used vehicles. So lets say, i pass detailRows in the data source.
Question is how do i pass these two lists to the two sub-reports? Can i use 
`new net.sf.jasperreports.engine.data.JRBeanCollectionDataSource($F{newVehiclesList})` as a datasource for sub report 1 and 
`new net.sf.jasperreports.engine.data.JRBeanCollectionDataSource($F{usedVehiclesList})` as datasource for sub report 2?
Is there anything else that needs to be done apart from what i mentioned? Do i need to create and pass any variables? Is the appropriate use of the list of lists as i have listed above or is it `$F{detailRows}.get(0)`?

I created a field detailRows in the main report as type list. I then pass the following to the subreport data source expression, `new net.sf.jasperreports.engine.data.JRBeanCollectionDataSource($F{detailRows}`
Is there any way i can pass the `newVehiclesList` from detailRows to the sub-report?

Thanks!

Answer (score 6):

Selecting your SubReport you can set the property "Connection type" as "Use a data source expression" and inside the property "Data Source Expression" you set this:

```
new net.sf.jasperreports.engine.data.JRBeanCollectionDataSource($F{yourFieldHere})
```

Where your "yourFieldHere" is a list (don't forget to set the "Field Class" inside your field properties as a java.util.List as well)

Comment: Thanks for the response. What i am mainly confused about is how to pass an individual list from a collection of lists to a particular sub report. In the above instance my data source consists of detailRows which is a collection of newVehiclesList and usedVehiclesList. How do i pass newVehiclesList to new vehicles sub-report?

Comment: Let me see if I get it straight, do you have a List<List<?>> ? If you do, you can do exactly how I said in my answer, except that you will need two subReports.

Comment: Yea i do. So first subreport you suggest i create a field and make it type collection and then second subreport, under the first one i create a field and make it type list? Also, i am using a bean and the second subreport would have the same fields as the attributes in the bean??

Comment: You have a provider called detailRows(it's a List that have two Lists inside it), that is a list and you pass it from java, right?

Comment: Yes sir, thats what i set in the data source and pass it to the fillreport.

Answer (score 1):

Ok, then you need create two fields with the Field Class as java.util.List, one for each list (newVehiclesList and usedVehiclesList).

Put your two SubReports wherever you want and click on each one doing the following steps:

Change the "Connection type" to "Use a datasource expression" then change the "Data Source Expression" to new net.sf.jasperreports.engine.data.JRBeanCollectionDataSource($F{yourField})

Done.

ps: In order to use the fields inside your newVehiclesList and usedVehiclesList you have to create them inside of their own subReports.

Comment: I tried it and it didnt work, here is what i did... so detailRows is a list of lists containing, newVehicles and usedVehicles(list of beans with fields defined as Strings). In the main report i create a field, detailRows(as a list) and pass through data source new net.sf.jasperreports.engine.data.JRBeanCollectionDataSource($F{detailRows}).. then in the sub report i create another field newVehicles and pass as data source  - new net.sf.jasperreports.engine.data.JRBeanCollectionDataSource($F{newLeads}).. then in the sub- sub report i create field,

Comment: jasperVehicleId(an attribute in my JasperVehicle bean) and try to display the same. i get the message, JRException: Error retrieving field value from bean : detailRows.. any idea what i am doing wrong?

Comment: You've commited a mistake here: " In the main report i create a field, detailRows(as a list) and pass through data source". If it's your main source, it should be passed through your java code and there's no need to create it as a field inside you main report.
Only your "SubSources" newVehicles and usedVehicles need fields.

Comment: You are right. I removed the field from the main report and now it runs fine but nothing gets printed. I put a static text label as a column name and am just printing one value (Text field) both in a detail band to see if it works and nothing gets printed. Thanks for pointing out my mistake.

Comment: btw i did check my detailRows and it does contain two records, so am not passing an empty data source, com.edmunds.dwh.jasperreports.JasperDealerVehicle@33c282a1, com.edmunds.dwh.jasperreports.JasperDealerVehicle@270e3293]

Comment: Also, what should my connection type and connection/data source expression be since i am no longer creating and passing a field, detailRows? I am sorry to bother you but the book does not go beyond basic examples.

Comment: You're not bothering me, don't you worry.

This new scenario is a little bit weird because at least the static text should be printed. Did you have created the field you want to display? Try to put only the static text inside the column header and tell me what happened. 

About the connection/data it's only for your subReports, you told me you got 2 Lists inside you JasperDealerVehicle object. So if you want to put them inside a SubReport you need to create a field for each one and finally use it as a connection/data source expression the same way as I told you before.

Comment: Thanks. So i removed the field and only have a static text field in the detail band and it doesn't get printed. Even though i would eventually have multiple lists in the one parent list, right now i am just trying with one list within a list to see if things work. So i am passing the main parent list in the data source, child list1 in the sub report and declaring a field for an attribute of the bean in the sub sub report.

Comment: Is it throwing any exception? About the subreport, did you create a field that represents your child list 1? It should have the same name as your attribute in your bean.

Comment: No exception. Just creates the rest of the report minus this addition. Yes i did create an attribute in the sub sub report and it matches the attribute name in the bean. Sub report has a field name of the list (newVehiclesList) which gets passed to sub sub report via the data source(new net.sf.jasperreports.engine.data.JRBeanCollectionDataSource($F{newVehiclesList})). Sub sub report has a field, jasperVehicleId and that matches the bean attribute.

Comment: public JasperDealerVehicle(String vehicleId) {
        setJasperVehicleId(vehicleId);

    }
   
   private String jasperVehicleId;
    
    public String getJasperVehicleId() {
        return jasperVehicleId;
    }

    public void setJasperVehicleId(String jasperVehicleId) {
        this.jasperVehicleId = jasperVehicleId;
    }

Comment: You also have to create a field inside your report referencing your list:

MainReport
|____fieldNewVehicleList - Type java.util.List
|____fieldUsedVehicleList - Type java.util.List

SubReportNewVehicle
|______fieldNewVehicleName - Type String

SubReportUsedVehicle
|______fieldUsedVehicleName - Type String


Your report seems like this?

(copy and paste my comment in somewhere else to see it right)

Comment: So if i am understanding you correctly, do i have to create two fields in my main report (one list of new vehicles and one list of used vehicles?), if so what would their data sources be?

Comment: btw in my sub report (not the sub sub report referencing the fields that are properties of the bean) i do reference the list

Comment: Their data source you have already setted, it's your "List<JasperDealerVehicle>". Creating those 2 fields you'll have access to each list inside each Bean(JasperDealerVehicle) of your main list. 
Because of this you can use your fields as providers for your SubReports.

Comment: What do you mean when you say sub sub? there are three levels?

Comment: I have a main report, which has 4 sub reports in the summary tab. 3 of those sub reports are using parameter map as their data source. Last onewould be details coming from bean collection data source. So first level is main report, second level is subdetail report (using list of lists as a data source) and third level is one sub sub report containing usedVehicles and another sub sub report containing newVehicles. Hope i sound more clear to you than i sound to myself:)...

Comment: this is what i had in mind and was trying:http://imageshack.us/photo/my-images/846/20120716112056951.jpg/

Comment: That's why we were not speaking the same language haha It's easy as well, you just have to pass to your SubReport the parameter that represents your collection coming from your java code, it's setted by this expression $P{REPORT_DATA_SOURCE} (this is native, you don't have to configure it) inside your Data Source Expression, you still have to put the connection type as "Use a datasource expression". Try this and let me know

Comment: I know, should have posted an image sooner.. haha...Sorry so if my java code is setting detailRows(List containing list of usedVehicles & newVehicles), then my subreport i create a field detail Rows and pass the following to the data source expression?new net.sf.jasperreports.engine.data.JRBeanCollectionDataSource($F{detailRows})

Comment: Nope, you don't need this field because when you set your provider through the java code it's stored and you can get it with  $P{REPORT_DATA_SOURCE} then you use it like this: new net.sf.jasperreports.engine.data.JRBeanCollectionDataSource($P{REPORT_DATA_SOURCE})

Should work fine.

Comment: The comments are not to be used as an interactive debugger.

Answer (score 0):

i was the same problems with you and i solved it using the tag List of jasper, i used datasource in my class java, for example:
parameter.put("MyList",  new JRBeanCollectionDataSource(ListObjects));
in JRXML

In palete of Jasper, choose the tag LIST and drag and drop in your relatory
after choose

- create new dataset
- create new dataset from a connection… ...
- in data adapter choose new data adapter - collection of javabeans
- use a JRDatasource expression
- go in lis of parameters and choose you list op objects (MyList)

now go to outline of jasper and 
 - dataset properties
 - edit and query filter ... ...
 - javabean
 - search you class (I using eclipse, so it's easy to search my class) 
 - add fields to use